# What is the support of the Dirichlet Function?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The Dirichlet function is defined as:

- if $x$ is rational, $f(x)=0$,
- if $x$ is irrational, $f(x)=1$.

What is its support?

I think the answer is the set of irrational numbers.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: There are multiple notions of [Support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of a function, and the answer depends on which one you use. You should include your definition of support in the question.

Comment: the support of a function is clusre of the set of all points where the function is non-zero

Answer (score 0):

Use your definition, $\{x|f\neq 0\}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ , whose closure is $\mathbb{R}$. So the support is $\mathbb{R}$.